# Downloading a file with wget using multiple connections

Tags: linux, download, wget

How to download a file with wget using multiple connection in which each connection downloads a part of the file?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430810/wget-download-with-multiple-simultaneous-connections

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple simultaneous downloads using Wget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430810/multiple-simultaneous-downloads-using-wget)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

use [aria2](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/)

```
 aria2c -x 16 [url] #where 16 is the number of connections
```

OR

Just repeat the `wget -r -np -N [url]` for as many threads as you need. This isn’t pretty and there are surely better ways to do this, but if you want something quick and dirty it should do the trick.

Comment: The solution you gave for wget downloads a single file multiple times resulting in multiple copies, but I want to download a single file using multiple connection, each of which downloads its part of file.

Comment: `wget` solution doesn't download one file in multiple threads: The options used `-r` is recursive, `-np` (`--no-parent`) — don't ascend to the parent directory, `-N` (`--timestamping`) — don't re-retrieve files unless newer than local. But `wget` would definitely work if you're downloading a mirror of a site.

Comment: @Trix -x, --max-connection-per-server=NUM The maximum number of connections to one  server for each download.
                              Possible Values: 1-16
                              Default: 1
                              Tags: #basic, #http, #ftp

Comment: perhaps the flag -nc was intended, not -np

Comment: The link in the answer is 404

Comment: On Ubuntu you can install aria2 with `sudo apt-get install aria2`

Answer (score 32):

```
sudo apt-get install axel
axel -n 5 url
```

Would do the work!

[Axel](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/axel.1.html) is a lightweight program that helps with the downloads and supports multiple connections.

Want to resume download after a disconnection?
No problem, just repeat the command and axel will take care of it.

Comment: Not very useful with long S3 pre-signed URLs due to `Can't handle URLs of length over 1024` limitation

Comment: I have the same issue with S3 pre-signed URLs. This command is totally useless and it doesn't make sense to have a 1024 character limit on a URL in 2023...

Answer (score -1):

Axel supports visual indicator.
axel -a -n [X parts] [URL]

Comment: What is the additional insight you contribute on top of https://stackoverflow.com/a/35307402/7733418 ?