# How to concurrently run 40 wget commands in Microsoft Windows environment?

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I would like to stress test a website using wget commands. How to concurrently run 40 wget commands in Microsoft Windows environment?

I have tried writing command script but the wget command will be triggered one by one.

Comment: question should be redirected to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430810/wget-download-with-multiple-simultaneous-connections Also, are you sure running 40 wget commands is the best way to stress test a website?

Comment: If you're establishing more than 20 concurrent connections you need to disable rate limiting.  See https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/18667011-c034-43bc-ab2e-0e87bf811e5e/windows-7-increase-the-limit-of-concurrent-tcp-connections-not-related-to-eula-file-sharing?forum=w7itpronetworking

Answer (score 2):

You can use `for /L` to run a loop 40 times, and `start` to launch the program without waiting.  From the command line:

```
for /L %a in (1 1 40) do start wget the_url
```

From a batch file, you would use the same command, except use `%%a` instead of `%a`

Because wget is a command-line program, you will see 40 new console windows open up, which should close automatically as the wget commands finish.  You can avoid this by using `start /b` to run the commands all in the same console.  In this case, I would also pipe the output of each command to NUL, to avoid having forty instances writing to the same console.

```
for /L %a in (1 1 40) do start /b wget the_url >nul
```

Comment: `start /b` would launch each thread non-blocking, but in the same window.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `&` operator along with the `start` command:

```
C:\> start wget URL1 & start wget URL2 & start wget URL3.....
```

Comment: `&` doesn't make them all launch at the same time.  Each instance will only start once the one before has exited.

Comment: @rojo - that would only be true if the /WAIT option were used. This solution should work, but it would be simpler to put each START WGET on a new line and ditch the `&`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `start` was not a [part of this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30633841/1) when I left that comment.  Tricky.  `-_-`