# How do I use the --accept-regex option for downloading a website with wget?

Tags: regex, wget

I'm trying to download an archive of my website — [3dsforums.com](http://3dsforums.com) — using wget, but there are millions of pages I *don't* want to download, so I'm trying to tell wget to only download pages that match certain URL patterns, and yet I'm running into some roadblocks.

As an example, this is a URL I would like to download:

http://3dsforums.com/forumdisplay.php?f=46

...so I've tried using the `--accept-regex` option:

```
wget -mkEpnp --accept-regex "(forumdisplay\.php\?f=(\d+)$)" http://3dsforums.com
```

But it just downloads the home page of the website.

The only command that remotely works so far is the following:

```
wget -mkEpnp --accept-regex "(\w+\.php$)" http://3dsforums.com
```

This provides the following response:

```
Downloaded 9 files, 215K in 0.1s (1.72 MB/s)
Converting links in 3dsforums.com/faq.php.html... 16-19
Converting links in 3dsforums.com/index.html... 8-88
Converting links in 3dsforums.com/sendmessage.php.html... 14-15
Converting links in 3dsforums.com/register.php.html... 13-14
Converting links in 3dsforums.com/showgroups.php.html... 14-29
Converting links in 3dsforums.com/index.php.html... 16-80
Converting links in 3dsforums.com/calendar.php.html... 17-145
Converting links in 3dsforums.com/memberlist.php.html... 14-99
Converting links in 3dsforums.com/search.php.html... 15-16
Converted links in 9 files in 0.009 seconds.
```

Is there something wrong with my regular expressions? Or am I misunderstanding the use of the `--accept-regex` option? I've been trying all sorts of variations today but I'm not quite grasping what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 5):

`wget` by default uses POSIX regex `\d` class is expressed as `[:digit:]` and `\w` class is expressed as `[:word:]`, plus why all the grouping? If your `wget` is compiled with PCRE support make your life easier and do it as:

wget -mkEpnp --regex-type pcre --accept-regex "forumdisplay.php\?f=\d+$" http://3dsforums.com

but... that will not work because your forum software creates automatic session IDs (`s=<session_id>`) and injects them in all the links, so you need to account for those as well:

```
wget -mkEpnp --regex-type pcre --accept-regex "forumdisplay\.php\?(s=.*)?f=\d+(s=.*)?$" http://3dsforums.com
```

The only problem is that now your files will be saved with the session ID in their names so you'll have to add another step when `wget` is finished - to bulk rename all the files with the session ID in their names. You could probably do it by piping `wget` to `sed`, but I'll leave that to you :)

And if your `wget` doesn't support PCRE this pattern will end up being quite long, but lets hope it does...